# Errors when using animation and CustomPainter widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Hello I'm very new to flutter and I'm trying to work out an error, but I can't seem to find anything on this matter. Below is my current code:

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  Test({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  TestState createState() => TestState();
}

class TestState extends State<Test> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  double circleOneFraction = 0.0;

  Animation<double> circleOneAnimation;
  AnimationController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    //width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500), vsync: this);
    circleOneAnimation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 0.5).animate(controller)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          circleOneFraction = circleOneAnimation.value;
        });
      });
    controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      painter: MyPainter(circleOneFraction),
      child: Container(),
      willChange: true,
      isComplex: true,
    );
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  double circleOneFraction;

  MyPainter(this.circleOneFraction);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final heightOfPaint = size.height;
    final widthOfPaint = size.width;

    Paint paint = Paint();

    Path mainBackground = Path();
    mainBackground.addRect(Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, widthOfPaint, heightOfPaint));
    paint.color = colors.blueColor;
    canvas.drawPath(mainBackground, paint);

    //TEST
    paint.color = Colors.white;
    var circleOneCenter = Offset(0.25 * widthOfPaint, heightOfPaint * 1.1);
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    canvas.drawCircle(circleOneCenter, circleOneFraction * widthOfPaint, paint);

    var circleTwoCenter = Offset(0.8 * widthOfPaint, heightOfPaint * 1.1);
    canvas.drawCircle(circleTwoCenter, widthOfPaint * 0.38, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

I want to make an animation with drawing an expanding circle at the bottom of the screen, using CustomPainter widget. When launching the app, I get about an error every milisecond (which I assume is from refreshing the background. The only type of error message I get, is "Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null".
I cant seem to work out where the issue is, with the very undescriptive error message.
I hope somebody can help point out my mistake.

Edit: I do see the animation unfold, but just have a red error-screen popping up every milisecond.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the exact error text when dealing with errors, including any line number or stack trace information that was shown.

Answer (score 1):

Without more information like the exact output of the error, my guess would be this function is causing the error:

```
@override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return null; // Returning null instead of a bool. 
  }
```

The return for this function is supposed to be a bool and you are always returning null regardless of the function call. Since you are overriding the base function it is likely being called in code you do not see, causing your error. Either create some valid logic for the function for when it should repaint or I would recommend setting it to default to false;

Returning false is what the example shown in the flutter documentation for [CustomPainter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) class does.